# Как сделать красивый выбор даты в android?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу сделать такой alertDialog для выбора месяца и года без выбор дня.
Подскажите как называется этот компоненты и как его реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

класс называется DatePickerDialog, гугл рекомендует его реализовывать через фрагмент, а точней DialogFragment, реализовать примерно так:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());   
  }
}
```

для того чтобы убрать день - желательно создать свой класс забрав с семплов:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java
или после того как получится сделать диалог, попробуйте сделать так:

```
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Класс называется `DatePickerDialog`, а внутри он используется `DatePicker`.

Проблема в том, что скрыть колонку с днём просто так не выйдет. Тут надо либо при помощи рефлексии получить ссылку на приватное поле внутри `DatePicker` и работать с ним, либо взять [код из исходников SDK](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java) и на его основе сделать свой. С первым подходом есть проблема в том, что на разной версии андроида `DatePicker` внутри работает по-разному. Вот в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789907/hide-day-month-or-year-from-datepicker-in-android-5-0-lollipop) есть замечательный пример, как это решается на разных версиях.

Comment: Про `DatePickerDialog` я знаю но это не то.

В студии я нашел NumberPicker но дизайн у него совсем не такой как на картинке. Я в принципе могу 3 таких NumberPicker добавить и будет та же самая дата что на картинке. Но дизайн не тот.